# Styling a-expanded="true"

Tags: css

How can I use the attribute expanded when I style it using CSS?

I got a dropdown which is

```
expanded="false"
```

and when it's open it becomes

`expanded="true"`.

There is no class so I was wondering if I can use that attribute for styling?

Thanks

Comment: please post the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div[ expanded="true"]{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div expanded="true">huujioujo</div>
```

Comment: _I got a dropdown_, yet you used a `div` in your fiddle.

Comment: you can use div,list,class,id or more for same style

Comment: Then why don't you use it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to:

```
div[expanded=true] { color: red; }
```

However, there isn't a expanded HTML attribute that I know of? It would be better to just add the class .expanded instead of using expanded="true".